# how to parse a search query that uses the structure of a polish notation?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

My application has a search box that supports queries with the following structure:

**Input:**
a string with the following structure:

```
<operand><phrase><category>  <operand><phrase><category>  ...


<operand>: can be + or - to denote include or exclude and is optional

<phrase>: can be a single word or a word or sentence surrounded by quotes

<category>: is surrounded by square brackets and can be either [c1], [c2], or [c3]
```

An example of one query:

```
+car "tart berries"[fruit]  -"broccoli"[vegetable] "green onion"[vegetable] pepper[vegetable]  -"my keys"[object]
```

**Desired output :**

```
[
["+", "car",         ""],
["" , "tart berries","fruit"],
["-", "broccoli".,   "vegetable"],
["" , "green onion", "vegetable"],
["" , "pepper",      "vegetable"]
]
```

My code:

I use the following regex to capture groups:

```js
let re = /([+-]?)(\w+|".+?")(\[fruit\]|\[vegetable\]|\[object\])?/gi
var str = '+car "tart berries"[fruit]  -"broccoli"[vegetable] "green onion"[vegetable] pepper[vegetable]  -"my keys"[object]'

for (const match of str.matchAll(re)) {

    console.log(match);
}
```

Issue:

1. Items get repeated multiple time:

```
["+car", "+", "car"]
[""tart berries"[fruit]", "", ""tart berries"", "[fruit]"]
```

2. is there a way to exclude quotes from the results.

```
"tart berries" instead of ""tart berries""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get rid of the quotes in the regex, JS regexp does not support [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), so you will have to post-process the matches.

Also, to capture just `c1`/`c2`/`c3` values without square brackets, you need to replace `(\[a]|\[b]|\[c])?` with an optional non-capturing group and re-group the atlernatives as `(?:\[(a|b|c)])`.

Note that `"[^"]*"` is more efficient than `".+?"`.

You can use

```js
let re = /([+-]?)(\w+|"[^"]*")(?:\[(fruit|vegetable|object)])?/gi
const rx_quotes = /^"|"$/g;
var str = '+car "tart berries"[fruit]  -"broccoli"[vegetable] "green onion"[vegetable] pepper[vegetable]  -"my keys"[object]'
let result = [];
for (const match of str.matchAll(re)) {
    let [_,x,y,z] = match;
    y = y.replace(rx_quotes,'');
    if (z === undefined) z = "";
    result.push([x,y,z]);
}
console.log(result);
```

**Regex details**

- `([+-]?)` - Group 1: an optional `+` or `-` char
- `(\w+|"[^"]*")` - Group 2: one or more word chars or a string between double quotation marks
- `(?:\[(fruit|vegetable|object)])?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or  0 occurrences of

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `(fruit|vegetable|object)` - Group 3: any of the substring alternatives
  - `]` - a `]` char.